# Ubuntu Saucy 13.10 package repository doesn't seem to have ros-indigo-* packages, although I do see other packages like python-rosinstall

Tags: ros, packages, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the Ubuntu 13.10 Indigo installation instructions

*BUT*

sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-desktop-full

Fails, and I can verify this by looking at this URL:

(NOTE: Not enough karma to paste this link in)
<PACKAGES.ROS.ORG>  /ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages

and seeing that it doesn't contain any packages that match ros-indigo-*

So am I missing something?

Thanks,

Dan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129736/ubuntu-saucy-13.10-package-repository-doesn%27t-seem-to-have-ros-indigo-*-packages,-although-i-do-see-other-packages-like-python-rosinstall/) by [danp](https://answers.ros.org/users/12021/danp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Indigo is in a very pre-alpha state right now, and debs have not been released yet. Beyond being unreleased, it look like desktop-full is not yet built.

You can track the built state of indigo [here](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html).

If you're really, really interested, the indigo debs that are built are available in the shadow repository.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2